# How to get details of an express checkout - PayPal / Postman

Tags: node.js, paypal, postman, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to get the details of payment after test an express checkout.

When I go to
*https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-0CS36485JR5738828*
It shows the checkout and I click on confirm.
After that, I'm being redirected to *http://return.url/?paymentId=PAYID-MHKJM6A3W026542BR076654N&token=EC-0CS36485JR5738828&PayerID=HUGNJ49ZGF8CU*

Here I have the paymentID, but I can't find an endpoint to see the details of that payment.

And I have a Webhook too with the event `Checkout checkout buyer-approved`, if I simulate an event, the webhook responds and sends the data to my backend, but it doesn't do it when I do an express checkout.

Now I'm trying almost everything with Servistate (Postman-like), but the idea is to make an express checkout, and confirm that payment on the backend.

Note: On my backend, I'm using paypal-rest-sdk package to generate the payment and with that, the checkout url

Answer (score 0):

The PAYID token was created using the v1/payments API.

Use that API to [get the status of the payment](https://developer.paypal.com/api/payments/v1/#payment_get).

---

Note that the v1/payments API is deprecated, you should use the v2/checkout/orders API for payment processing instead. See the current [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) documentation, and be sure to read through the 5th bullet in 'Add and modify the code' which discusses a server integration.